# How to add a loonie jpeg to multiple Plotly pie charts

Tags: python, plotly, jpeg, pie-chart

I'm looking to add a loonie jpeg into a plotly pie chart that I've already created. Can't really share the data but it'll look something like this, where the amount in each year will add up to 1. There's 4 entries per year.

```
Year Status Amount
2012   a      0.8
2012   b      0.05
2012   c      0.11
2012   d      0.04
2013   a      0.83
2013   b      0.06
etc
```

Heres the code I used to make the plotly charts

```
    lst = list(df.groupby('Year'))

# here we want our grid to be 3 x 3
rows = 3
cols = 3

subplot_titles = [l[0] for l in lst]

specs=[[{'type':'pie'}]*cols]*rows

fig = make_subplots(
        rows=rows,
        cols=cols,
        subplot_titles=subplot_titles,
        specs=specs,  
        print_grid=True
)

for i, l in enumerate(lst):
    row = i // cols + 1
    col = (i % rows) + 1
    d = l[1]
    fig.add_trace(go.Pie(labels=d["Status"],
                         values = d["Amount"],
                         hovertemplate = "%{label}: <br>Value: %{value} ",
                         showlegend=True,
                         textposition='inside',
                         rotation=90),
     row=row,
     col=col    
    )
    
fig.update_layout(height = 1000,
                  width = 900,
                  autosize = False,
                  title="Yield", 
                  title_x=0.5)
fig.show()
```

The plots works fine and I got my 7 Pie charts all correct just looking to add a loonie jpeg over the plotly pie charts. Any help would be much appreciated.

[image: Loonie Jpeg File]

Comment: I was able to set an image as the background of the pie chart, but I could not find a way to support subplots. I saved the image in question locally and converted it to PNG format. You can use the PIL library to load the image and specify it as a source. I think you need to do a lot of manual trial and error to place it in the center.

Comment: I'll share an example of a background image in a single pie chart in [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1_3Qduf-kgj4joDQ5idjS7SALkXqOq6LA?usp=sharing) for your reference. If you're happy with this, go ahead and edit it, but disable the link if you don't want it.

Comment: Where do you want the image placed relative to the pie charts?

Comment: I'd like the loonie img to be in each pie chart, so when see a pie chart you should be looking at a loonie pie chart.

Comment: Have you checked the code and images from the links in the comments? Can you comment on whether it is necessary or not?

Comment: Yea I did check the code, really appreciate it @r - beginners, currently working on how I can get that image in the subplots.  I'm not the greatest at python but lots of trial and error as you said earlier.